# VBA Count number of cells in range

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to count the number of cells within a range to display on the status bar. Not sure how to count the number of cells within the range to use as the denominator for the progress bar. Any thoughts?

```
For Each cell In Range("E11:G28,E33:G50,E57:G74,E79:G96,E101:G118,E130:G147,E152:G169,E175:G192,E198:G215,E221:G238")
    **lTotal = Range.Cells.Count**
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing cell " & cell.AddressLocal & _
                                    "    " & Format((lCounter / lTotal), "0%")
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = "")
    lCounter = lCounter = 1
Next cell
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why are you running this line `cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = "")` continually through multiple columns? The row may unhide then hide again contuouly. Did you want to hide the row if *any* cell was blank - if so then just check for a sinle blank.

Comment: @brettdj thanks. I want to only hide the row if all of the cells in that row are blank.

e.g. if E11 is blank, but G11 is _not_ blank, do _not_ hide the row. If E11, F11 and G11 are blank, hide the row.

If you know a faster way to do this, I would really appreciate this because currently it is very slow.

Comment: I have updated my code to do that row by row rather than cell by cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version looks at your range, row by row, rather than by cell by cell

It also turns off `ScreenUpdating` to avoid flicker, resets the `StatusBar` etc

```
Sub ReCut() 
Dim rData As Range 
Dim rng1 As Range 
Dim rng2 As Range 
Dim rcell As Range 
Dim lngCnt As Long 
Dim lngCalc As Long 

Set rData = Range("E11:G28,E33:G50,E57:G74,E79:G96,E101:G118,E130:G147,E152:G169,E175:G192,E198:G215,E221:G238") 

For Each rng1 In rData.Areas 
ltotal = ltotal + rData.Rows.Count 
Next 

With Application 
    .ScreenUpdating = False 
    .EnableEvents = False 
    lngCalc = .Calculation 
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 

    For Each rng2 In rData.Areas 
        For Each rcell In rng2.Rows 
            rcell.EntireRow.Hidden = (.CountBlank(rcell) = 3) 
            lngCnt = lngCnt + 1 
            .StatusBar = "Processing row " & lngCnt & "    " & Format((lngCnt / ltotal), "0%") 
        Next rcell 
    Next 


    .ScreenUpdating = True 
    .EnableEvents = True 
    .Calculation = lngCalc 
    .StatusBar = vbNullString 
End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't hide rows where all of the cells in the range, in that row are blank. It doesn't actually hide any rows.

Also, lTotal = rData.Rows.Count returns 18 as opposed to 180.

Update: This is because if there is a formula, counta() considers it not empty. All the cells have formulas.

Comment: But your range is only columns E:G in each row? The second issue is my fault as the range has multiple areas and my answer loops through the first one only. Will update.

Comment: The correct answers is to replace
`cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (.CountA(cell) =0)`
with
`cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (Application.CountBlank(cell) = 5)`

Just need to figure out the correct row counting.

Comment: Updated for the areas. count is fine now. I think though you want `.CountBlank(rcell) = 3)` rather than `5`?

Comment: yep, 3 rather than 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Home()
    Dim cell As Range, N As Long
    For Each cell In Range("E11:G28,E33:G50,E57:G74,E79:G96,E101:G118,E130:G147,E152:G169,E175:G192,E198:G215,E221:G238").Areas
        N = N + cell.Cells.Count
    Next cell
    Debug.Print N
End Sub
```

This counts all the cells in your range.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Dim rData As Range
Set rData = Range("E11:G28,E33:G50,E57:G74,E79:G96,E101:G118,E130:G147,E152:G169,E175:G192,E198:G215,E221:G238")
lTotal = rData.Count
For Each cell In rData.Cells
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing cell " & cell.AddressLocal & _
                                    "    " & Format((lCounter / lTotal), "0%")
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = "")
    lCounter = lCounter + 1
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Range(Selection.Address).Count
```

Comment: uses: Range(Selection.Address).Count

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.